# angular 1.5 method .name in export angular.module

Tags: angularjs

I've been looking tutorial and documents; but i dont understand  the code below. there is 2 pieces of code from 2 files; the service; and the file where import the service.

this is a piece code of a  service angular file (address-local.js) :

```
    export default angular.module('erp.services.addressLocal', [])
      .factory('addressLocal', addressLocal)
      .name;


    /* @ngInject */
    function addressLocal($http) {
```

and this is a piece of code of file where is injected the service (account.js):

```
    import addressLocalService from '../services/address-local';
```

my question is:

- what does .name method in export; most of examples i've seen on the web dont use .name method
- what is the sense use 'erp.services.addressLocal' in export; when in the import is not used, just an 'import addressLocalService'; what is the full documentation syntax ?
- /* @ngInject */, is usefull?

where i can find complete  documentation about .name or all the methos i can use in the "export" ? it's ES6 mixed with Angular?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's examine the lines one by one:

```
angular.module('erp.services.addressLocal', [])
```

This defines a new angular module named `'erp.services.addressLocal'`. The name could be anything. A module is just a repository of components (services, controllers, etc.). The returned value is the created angular module.

```
.factory('addressLocal', addressLocal)
```

This adds a service named `'addressLocal'` to the angular module. The service is defined thanks to a factory function, `addressLocal`, defined right after. This returns the angular module.

```
.name
```

This allows accessing the name of the module. This value (i.e. 'erp.services.addressLocal') is what is exported by the ES6 module defined in this file.

```
/* @ngInject */
function addressLocal($http) {
```

This is the factory function which creates and returns the addressLocal service. It uses the injected $http service. @ngInject is used by a tool used at build time, named ng-annotate, which allows transforming the above code to

```
['$http', function($http)]
```

This strange notation is necessary if you minify your code, because the minifier will change `$http` to something meaningless and shorter like `a`, and angular uses argument names to know what to inject.

```
import addressLocalService from '../services/address-local';
```

This allows importing what is exporting from the fine address-local.js, i.e. the module name. I don't know what the code after this line does with it. But the variable name is badly named, since `addressLocalService` is not the addressLocalService, but the name of the module defined in the first file.

Comment: thanks JB for your nice explanation ... wich would be for you the correct line for the import ?

Comment: If the goal is to get the name of the module, the line you have is correct. It's the variable (addressLocalService) that should be better named. What does the code do with this variable?

Comment: it's just imported in another form component to get the records from an  api rest full, i can use another name .? or how i can use 'erp.services.addressLocal' default name? the method .name is really useful?

Comment: That doesn't make it clear. Edit your question and post the code coming after the import.